# How to return incorrect characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript to check, if a string contains invalid characters; allowed characters are `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `-`:

```
var str = 'Some string!',
    invalid_characters = [];

if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/.test(str) == false) {
  console.log('Invalid characters: ' + invalid_characters.join(', '));
}
else {
  console.log('String is OK.');
}
```

So in the exaple above,  and `!` are incorrect. How can I get these characters to the array `invalid_characters` (each character only once without duplicates)? Thanks.

Comment: str.split and loop trough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out the characters that don't comply with your pattern.

```js
var str = 'Some string!!!';

var invalid_characters = str.split('').filter(function(char){
    return !/[a-zA-Z0-9-]/.test(char)
})

// Filtering out duplicates
invalid_characters = invalid_characters.filter(function(char, pos) {
    return invalid_characters.indexOf(char) == pos;
})

console.log(invalid_characters) //[" ","!"]
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to remove duplicates? For `var str = 'Some string!!';` it will return `[" ","!","!"]`

Comment: @Legionar use array.indexOf(word)<0 to check if word already exist

Comment: @Jonasw yes, but inside `filter` function it will not work.

Comment: Oops yeah sorry, I had skipped this part. I have added a dupes filter

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best and easiest solution, but it should work :)

```
characters=str.split("");
wrong=[];
characters.forEach(function(character){
    //check if wrong
    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/.test(character) === false){
        //check if duplicate
        if(wrong.indexOf(character)<0){
            wrong.push(character);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not return each *wrong* character only once without duplicates

Comment: Thank you, this is also solution.

Comment: @Legionar : no worries

Answer (score 1):

The following should do most of the job for you.

```js
var str = 'Some! string! £';

var matches = str.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]{1}/g);
if (matches) {
  var invalid_characters = matches.filter(function(char, pos) {
    return matches.indexOf(char) == pos;
  });
  console.log('Invalid characters: "' + invalid_characters + '"');
} else {
  console.log('String is OK.');
}
```

JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6pj33Ly/1/)

This is basically an inversion of your regex pattern, with the global regex flag applied (to make sure the match() picks up all matches).

I have not included any deduplication code as there are libraries out there to do it, such as [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array). I also quite like Jeremy's reply in this thread.

EDIT: I added deduplication as per Jeremy's answer as it's quite succinct. Normally I would wrap `_.uniq()` around the array from the [underscore docs here](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

Comment: Thank you, this is also solution.